# Multiple groups of RAID devices in btrfs

Tags: raid, btrfs

In btrfs, is it possible to have multiple groups of devices, and each group is in different btrfs RAID? For example, 2 devices in raid0 and 4 in raid1?

Comment: Is btrfs stable/production ready now?

Comment: I like ZFS :) But really, is BTRFS in wide use yet?

Comment: I don't think it is production ready yet and not yet in wide use.

Comment: I'll be using it on my new PC/server. I have been using it on my current PC for about 3 months and I haven't had any problems so it's stable enough for me.

Comment: Well any filesystem where there is no recovery available is not for prime time in my opinion (i.e. btrfs has no fsck).

Comment: It has btrfsck.